# Are polyester paintbrush bristles toxic?

Tags: drywall, walls, painting, paint

I did spot touch up painting using the following Home Depot Paint rollers. I applied two coats of Sherwin William White Shadow flat paint, 20 minutes apart. After that, I got many paint fibers stuck/glued on the wall? Over 50 and counting.

Sanding does not work to remove them.
My question is are the  paint brush bristles toxic (from breathing fumes) ? I sleep around 2 feet away from the wall. They seem to only be made from polyester fibers. Curious if there are any other hidden compounds in paintbrush fibers.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/9-in-x-3-8-in-High-Density-Polyester-Knit-Paint-Roller-Cover-3-Pack-RS-1433/100090787

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps there may be a more valid concern for the amount in your clothes…

Comment: Roller nap is not "paintbrush bristles," for a point of clarity in asking the question.

Comment: Think they are only toxic if you start putting ketchup on the rollers and eat them.  Might not even be toxic unless you eat about ten or twenty at a time.

Comment: next time duct tape and untape the roller before using it. better rollers are better, but more costly.

Comment: hi @dandavis I just learned that trick from am contractor today, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR NO

I imagine if you ate a *lot* of polyester (crip659 suggests using ketchup to make them taste better - that worked with almost anything when I was a kid) then you might have a problem. But realistically, no.

There are two potential concerns here, neither of which should be an issue for you:

- Fibers

Lots of little fibers can cause problems. How much of a problem depends a lot on the type of fiber (e.g., asbestos). But you don't really have a lot of fibers here. And more importantly, they are stuck to the wall! The problem with fibers is if you breathe them in. Just make sure to clean up any fibers that get loose and you won't have a problem.

- Fumes

There are no fumes from consumer use of polyester (or most other plastics) unless you burn the polyester, which is not a recommended way of getting it off of your wall.

There are fumes from paint. Follow the directions (should be on the can) for proper ventilation following painting and you should be fine. But again, that would be the paint, not the rollers or brushes which are basically inert. Paint has to dry - and the issue is what gets into the air when it dries. Rollers and brushes are designed to be solid objects that don't change (except "wearing out") from use - i.e., use, wash and dry and they should be substantially the same as when they were new. If they're the same, then nothing came out of them (and into the air to get into you).

Comment: Mine was canned peas, it took a lot of ketchup for them to go down.  Probably the only time I knew my parents were lying, telling me they were good for me.